# Java блокирует апплеты

Tags: applet, java

После обновления java стала блокировать абсолютно все апплеты. Пытался сменить уровень безопасности с высокого на любой другой, не выходит, после перезагрузки все обратно выставляется. В панели управления java во вкладке безопасность нет возможности добавить сайт в белый список (т.е. такой кнопки там вообще нет).

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: до какой версии java обновили?

Comment: @huffman 1.7.0_13

Answer (score 1):

Обновите до версии Java 7 Update 51 http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp там ваша проблема должна быть уже решена.

Comment: отчасти помогло. теперь могу добавлять сайты в белый лист и уровень безопасности сохраняется. но апплеты все равно не отображаются. выдает ошибку: CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/Entertaiment/Desktop/Expert_system.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Sat Jan 25 11:39:29 MSK 2014,length=31373